# Bigquery query failure handling

Tags: php, google-bigquery

I am trying to make sure that all my *streaming* queries are inserted successfully, and it seems as though some of these queries are not being inserted correctly.

There are no errors being thrown however I am not using the data returned by the insert request as I do not know how errors are structured.

Here is my insertion code:

```
    $rows = array();
    $row = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableDataInsertAllRequestRows;
    $row->setJson($data);
    $rows[0] = $row;
    $request = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableDataInsertAllRequest;
    $request->setKind('bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest');
    $request->setRows($rows);
    return $this->service->tabledata->insertAll($project, $dataset, $tableid, $request);
```

The above code excludes the authentication/setting up the client & service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this method

```
/**
 * 
 * @param Google_Client $client
 * @param type $project_id
 * @param type $dataset_id
 * @param type $rows
 * @return mixed
 * @throws Google_Service_Exception
 */
public function BQ_Tabledata_InsertAll($client, $project_id, $dataset_id, $rows) {
    $success = true;
    $failed_lines = array();
    $last_reason = '';
    $ret = array(
        'success' => &$success,
        'last_reason' => &$last_reason,
        'failed_lines' => &$failed_lines,
    );
    $bq = new Google_Service_Bigquery($client);
    $request = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableDataInsertAllRequest();
    $request->setRows($rows);
    try {
        $resp = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableDataInsertAllResponse();
        $resp = $bq->tabledata->insertAll($project_id, $dataset_id, static::tableId(), $request);
        $errors = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableDataInsertAllResponseInsertErrors();
        $errors = @$resp->getInsertErrors();
        if (!empty($errors)) {
            $error_msg = "\r\nRequest Headers: \r\n" . json_encode($client->request->getRequestHeaders()) . "\r\nResponse Headers: \r\n" . json_encode($client->request->getResponseHeaders()) . "\r\nRequest Body:\r\n" . $client->request->getPostBody() . "\r\nResponse Body:\r\n" . $client->request->getResponseBody() . "\r\n";
            if (is_array($errors)) {
                foreach ($errors as $eP) {
                    $arr = $eP->getErrors();
                    $line = $eP->getIndex();
                    if (is_array($arr)) {
                        foreach ($arr as $e) {
                            switch ($e->getReason()) {
                                case "stopped":
                                    break;
                                case "timeout":
                                    $failed_lines[] = $line;
                                    $last_reason = $e->getReason();
                                    $error_msg.= sprintf("Timeout on line %s, reason: %s, msg: %s\r\n", $line, $e->getReason(), $e->getMessage());
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    $error_msg.= sprintf("Error on line %s, reason: %s, msg: %s\r\n", $line, $e->getReason(), $e->getMessage());
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        $error_msg.= json_encode($arr) . "\r\n";
                    }
                }
                $this->setErrorMessage($error_msg);
            } else {
                $this->setErrorMessage($errors);
            }
            //print_r($errors);
            //exit;
            $success = false;
        }
        return $ret;
    } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
        $this->setErrors($e->getErrors())->setErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been playing around with this function however I am not able to actually get the error results back from this, it seems no matter what happens its not setting the errors. Looking at the BQ interface shows that the count for errors does go up however

Comment: @EwanWalker the errors are there, and the code is good we use in production, but these errors are rare, probably 1-2 per week.

Comment: That's weird, I had over 30k in our application (reported by bigquery) and the provided code example does not seem to report an error for one.. Ill have to dig deeper

Comment: @EwanWalker try posting something above the limits or log response to a file.